# How to achieve dynamism with Joomla?

Tags: joomla, radio-button, joomla3.0

i'm new to Joomla and i'm considered in the phase of discovering it yet , my problem here is that i'm using Joomla to make a cafe online ordering website , i want the customer to access the website and make his order from it, so i have to provide him with an active menu containing the cafe menu items, so i have to provide a radio buttons(or something like that) in order to give the customer the ability to choose his order items and to confirm his choices at last. i searched a lot about how to make that using Joomla and didn't reach to any thing , so it will be great if anyone can help me in such stuff.

Comment: so you want the cafe products as menu items rather than on the content are of the page? Not sure if I'm just tired and being dopey or actually a tad confused.

Comment: I want the cafe products to be listed as a big scrolled menu, but it's not the problem, the problem is that i can't make a radio buttons or an equivalent items in order to make this menu active and allow customers to use it to order their orders

Comment: I think he means like a restaurant menu not like a joomla menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not build complex custom forms with Joomla out-of-the-box.

The best solution depends on your needs - especially your further processing of the order.

If you just want to send it by mail to someone or to have it saved in the database, then it would be a enough to use a form extension for joomla. You will find many form extension on JED - they vary a lot in features, usability,flexibility and price. I often use breezingforms because it is very flexible and you can extend it with your own code (mostly).

If you want a full "shop" then you should have a look at the virtueMart extension for joomla. Or even at a shop system instead of joomla.

If you want full control you can write your own HTML and PHP Code and inject it into Joomla by a module such as Sourcerer from nonumber.nl. Or you write your own extension...